# Link clickable area larger than its image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, hyperlink

I have searched for quite a while and read many of the other answers on this topic. I have a set of image links for which the clickable areas overextend the images, but only on the bottom. The images are the social icons in the site header.

Website link: http://brendanbikes.org/

stylesheet: http://brendanbikes.org/wp-content/themes/casper-wp-master/style.css?ver=3.9.1

Relevant class: .social-icons

I've tried changing the float of the individual images, line height, div container height, all to no avail. Why do the links only overextend on the bottom, and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by the default display of the `a` tags (display: inline;).

Add this CSS, and everything will be OK :

```
.social-icons a {
    display: inline-block !important; /* !important could be omitted */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything in Chrome 35.0.1916.153. Why do you expect it to?

Comment: @Palpatim is right - no change for me as well, on Chrome 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: Did you mean to change both `display: inline-block` and `height` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change height and width of inline elements. By specifying `display: inline-block`, you can then adjust the `height` of your `.social-icons a` objects:

Add to `.social-icons a` rule:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 1em;
```

Comment: That didn't work either - the hover behaves properly in Firefox 29.0.1, but misbehaves in the above Chrome version & Safari 7.0.5 (9537.77.4). Could something be wrong with the icon classes themselves?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit hacky, but adding the following forces cutoff of anything outside the container, and accounts for horizontal cutoff:

```
.social-icons a{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left:0.1vw;
    padding-right:0.1vw;
}
```

Hope this helps others with this.